# How to effectively use resources with mobile web development?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, cross-browser, subdomain

I am new to mobile web development and I'm trying to figure out the best structure. I have decided to use a sub domain to handle everything mobile with some JavaScript that points to that sub domain if it detects mobile.

My JavaScript file points to `http://m.mywebsite.com`. The sub domain is on the server at "root/mobile" so all the resources are mobile use can be grabbed there.

Here is my confusion: To use less resources and data, duplicate files I go back a directory. For example, to embed the logo image I would use `src="../images/logo.png"`. Wouldn't this be correct? Is there any disadvantages to doing this? I don't see a point in make a new images directory and placing a copy of the logo in there as it would use more data. Although, everywhere I look online people are making duplicate directories inside their mobile directory.

Perhaps it doesn't matter and I'm overthinking this. Or perhaps I'm looking in the wrong places... if this is the case, can someone provide useful links for starting out mobile use?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I get you right.

Whether or not the general (not mobile) resources folder is in different domain/subdomain, you can, to be on the safe side, refer to that folder by specifying the full URL (as long as the client has access to it. see CORS), rather than the relative URL.

```
src="http://m.mywebsite.com/images/logo.png"
src="http://m.mywebsite.com/mobile/images/logo.png"
src="http://mywebsite.com/images/logo.png"
```

Regarding images duplication, it is preferred to use smaller resolution copies of your desktop images for mobile versions. Smaller images result in better scaling on smaller screens and better latency (as the files are smaller in size for download).

So if you use smaller images for mobile version, you have no duplication anyway.

Take into consideraion that mostly storage costs are much cheaper than network traffic costs. So it is mostly better to have an appropriate resource for every relevant case, than to worry about one more or less directory.